# Performance of an ordered list in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

If I want to maintain an ordered list in Firebase, it seems like the best way to do it is to manually assign a priority to each item in my list. That means if I insert or remove an item from the list, I have to update the priorities of all the items following it. For an item at the beginning of the list, this means updating every item in the list.  Is there a better performing data structure or algorithm to use in this case?

Comment: I edited this to ask for a better d.s. or algorithm - the only fair answer to "is this fast enough?" is "did you profile it?"

Comment: What is the algorithm for sorting? Alphabetical? Numerical? By timestamp? I find myself pondering these sorts of nebulous questions about Firebase and usually find that they are much easier to solve once I've carefully identified the desired behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an ordered list by setting the priority of elements appropriately. Items in a list are ordered lexigraphically by priority, or if the priority can be parsed to a number, by numeric value.

If you want to insert items into the middle of an existing list, modifying the priorities of the existing items would work, but would be horribly inefficient. A better approach is just to pick a priority between the two items where you want to insert the value and set that priority for the new item.

For example, if you had element 1 with priority "a", and element 2 with priority "b", you could insert element 3 between the two with priority "aa" (or "aq", "az", etc).

In our experience, most times when you create an ordered list, you don't necessarily know the position in the list you want to insert the item beforehand. For example, if you're creating a Leader Board for a game, you don't know in advance that you want to place a new score 3rd in the list, rather you know you want to insert it at whatever position score 10000 gets you (which might happen to be third). In this case, simply setting the priority to the score will accomplish this. See our Leader Board example here:
https://www.firebase.com/tutorial/#example-leaderboard

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly. In this case I'd like to make a drag-and-drop list, so the ordering is defined by the user. I like the idea of inserting a priority between the two desired items, but I'm stuck on one thing: how do you know what the next item is when you're using a `child_added` callback? You only get the previous item, not the one after it.

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution for the arbitrary-order list, @RadfordSmith ?

Answer (score 0):

The Ruby gem [ranked_model](https://github.com/mixonic/ranked-model) has an interesting approach to this problem. It uses a position integer like many other "acts as list" implementations, but it doesn't rely on re-writing all the integers on each position move. Instead, it spaces the integers widely apart, and so each update may only affect one or two rows. Might be worth looking through the readme and code to see if this approach could fit here.